# requests and BeautifulSoup returns weird string

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, error-handling, request

Using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` I have made a program that puts all the data of a few `divs` elements inside of one `div` with the class `rightContent`. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://senf.ir/Company/5674580/%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'rightContent'}) #<div class="rightContent">
print(div.text)
```

This code works very well, the only problem is the output look very weird and almost unusable.
**Output:**

```
 




اهن الات - آهن آلات و ضایعات






                                        استان :
                                    

گلستان





                                        شهر :
                                    

گرگان





                                        گروه :
                                    

صنعت





                                        زیر گروه :
                                    

آهن آلات و ضایعات





 آدرس  اهن الات:





گلستان-گرگان- بلوار استراباد- جنب نبروگاه فشار قوی برق - بازار اهن پلاک اول 





 مدیریت اهن الات:


مهرشاد قادری





                                تلفن :
                            

برای مشاهده اطلاعات لطفا
                                وارد شوید
                                    و در صورت عدم عضویت از اینجا 
                                ثبت نام  کنید
                                





                                همراه :
                            

برای مشاهده اطلاعات لطفا
                                وارد شوید
                                    و در صورت عدم عضویت از اینجا 
                                ثبت نام  کنید                              
                                





                                ایمیل :
                            







                                بازدید :
                            

2





Process finished with exit code 0
```

**My Goal:**
How could i turn this output into a dictionary?

> One of my main problems doing this was the randomly placed spaces and the language being `Persian` not English.

Comment: Have you tried different encodings?

Comment: I didn't because i didn't get a error so the encodings should be fine though my new to this so correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for titles and values tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://senf.ir/Company/5674580/%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
title = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'DetailsTitle'})
value = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'DetailsValue'})

values = []
titles = []

for data in title: 
    values.append(data.get_text().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace(' ', ''))

for data in value: 
    titles.append(data.get_text().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace(' ', ''))

value_title_dict = dict(zip(values, titles))
```

`value_title_dict` would be:

```
{'استان :': 'گلستان', 'شهر :': 'گرگان', 'گروه :': 'صنعت', 'زیر گروه :': 'آهن آلات و ضایعات', ' آدرساهن الات:': 'گلستان-گرگان- بلوار استراباد- جنب نبروگاه فشار قوی برق - بازار اهن پلاک اول ', ' مدیریت اهن الات:': 'مهرشاد قادری', 'تلفن :': 'برای مشاهده اطلاعات لطفاوارد شویدو در صورت عدم عضویت از اینجا ثبت نامکنید', 'همراه :': 'برای مشاهده اطلاعات لطفاوارد شویدو در صورت عدم عضویت از اینجا ثبت نامکنید', 'ایمیل :': '', 'بازدید :': '40'}
```